# Assert that response body is empty list with rest-assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

How can I check with rest-assured (2.4.0) if the response json is an empty list?

Given the response `[]` (with header `content-type=application/json`) I tried:

```
.body(Matchers.emptyArray()) // expected: an empty array, actual: []
.body("/", Matchers.emptyArray()) // invalid expression /
.body(".", Matchers.emptyArray()) // invalid expression .
```

Comment: If it could help, this passes the matcher :

`Object array[] = new Object[0];`
`new MatcherAssert().assertThat(array, Matchers.emptyArray());`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The problem is (probably) that REST Assured returns a List and not an array (and Hamcrest differentiate between the two). You can do:

```
.body("", Matchers.hasSize(0))
```

or

```
.body("$", Matchers.hasSize(0))
```

or

```
.body("isEmpty()", Matchers.is(true))
```

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the problem. `Matchers.empty()` is the clearest way imo.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by what @Johan said I tried this and I think it tells more to reader than other suggestions.

```
.body("", equalTo(Collections.emptyList()))
```